# Expiry date and pagerefresh

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script for freebitco.in that will have an expiry date so that when the script expires, a pop up will show telling the user that the script has expired and ask the user to click ok so that the page will refresh.

But all I can get the script to do is show the expiry date and countdown but it won't show any pop up and I don't know why.

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 1, 2017 15:37:25").getTime();
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't show a popup as you don't have any code for a popup.
Try using:

```
if(confirm("EXPIRED - Reload?")){
    location.reload();
}
```

just after the line that reads

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr00rcuk/)

Comment: thankx alot, it actually worked, but i dont want it to hv another option for a user to click wether ok or cancle, i want it hv only an OK option that the user will click and the page will refresh

Comment: @PhyzyProgrammer You could use instead: 
    `alert("EXPIRED - Reload?");
    location.reload();`

Comment: okay bro, i was able to code the OKAY button alone but when i click it, it wont refresh pls what am i doing wrong, here is the code>>> if(alert("EXPIRED - Contact your Group Admin to get the Updated version of the Script!")){ location.reload(); }

Comment: thankx bro exactly what i was looking for, hv done it!!, thankx alot for your help, if only i could repay u sir,